# How to set a value in a cell of the table in a GridControl with OpenSwing

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a Java Enterprise Application based on the *OpenSwing framework*. I'm using the [`GridControl`](http://opensourcejavaphp.net/java/openswing/org/openswing/swing/client/GridControl.java.html) component to show a set of so called value objects, where the fields are mapped into columns.

After that data have been loaded from a list of value objects, how can I edit the content of a cell to change the value shown to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple!

```
int rowNumber = ....;
int colNumber = ....;
this.getTable().getGrid().setValueAt("HERE THE VALUE", rowNumber, colNumber);
```

where `this` is an instance of the `GridControl` class.